# Chrome - stop automatic updates

Tags: google-chrome, automation

Does anyone know a reliable way to stop chrome browser automatic updates?

I tried stopping the google services, but that doesn't help, after some time it updates again to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: So far from what I have tried, renaming Update folder to 'Update Disabled' (or similar) does the trick. 
Just stopping the update services would result in Chrome still being updated after some time.